# How to maintain a tcp socket in qt?

Tags: qt, sockets, networking

I have overloaded the incomingConnection function of QTcpServer at the server side with following code

```
void CtiServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug() << QString("CtiServer thread id = %1, thread = %2").arg(QString::number((uint)QThread::currentThreadId(), 16)).arg(QString::number((qlonglong)QThread::currentThread(), 16));
    ServerThread *thread = new ServerThread(socketDescriptor, this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}
```

Then in every thread i created a new QTcpSocket subclass object named ServerSocket,

```
void ServerThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << QString("ServerThread thread id = %1, thread = %2").arg(QString::number((uint)QThread::currentThreadId(), 16)).arg(QString::number((qlonglong)QThread::currentThread(), 16));
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
    serverSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    connect(serverSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), serverSocket, SLOT(handleRequest()));
    serverSocket->waitForDisconnected(-1);
}
```

The problem is whether `serverSocket->waitForDisconnected(-1)` is right or not.

I am trying to maintain the socket with this statement, util client send some message to notify the server socket that the connection should be shutdown, so that I could keep a long connection between server and client.

As a result, I could connect the disconnected signal and know when the client is down without bothering to set up some heart-beat protocol to detect whether a client is still alive or dead.

Or should I set up a heart-beat protocol and use code like following:

```
sock.disconnectFromHost();
sock.waitForDisconnected();
```

instead of `sock.waitForDisconnected(-1)`.

Comment: You should use Client SIGNAL disconnected() and connect it to your server side.For example: connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(funcA()));

Comment: What skg says, and enter the thread's event loop by calling exec() at the end of the function.

Comment: waitForDisconnected is blocking call, so your socket thread won't do any processing until your socket is disconnected